# Testing abstract models in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-management-command

I am trying to test some functionality of abstract base models in my Django app. I have been reading on how to do these tests and everyone seems to say that I need to create a test model.

So I have done so, I have crated a directory called `my_app/tests` and created a `models.py` in there. Where I have my test model `UniqueSlugTestModel`.

Now I guess I need to call `makemigrations` and `migrate` on the test app. So I add my new test app to the settings in the test and call migrate. But for some reason the `makemigrations` and `migrate` are not seeing that the `my_app.tests` app is not in settings. Why are they looking at different settings than the live settings that I am overriding in my tests?

Is this the best way to test abstract models in Django? How can I make the management commands look at the overridden settings?

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import override_settings

from my_app.tests.models import UniqueSlugTestModel


class UniqueSlugModelTestCase(TestCase):

    @override_settings(INSTALLED_APPS=settings.INSTALLED_APPS + ['my_app.tests'])
    def setUp(self):
        print(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
        call_command('makemigrations', 'my_app.tests', interactive=False)
        call_command('migrate', 'my_app.tests', interactive=False)

    @override_settings(INSTALLED_APPS=settings.INSTALLED_APPS + ['my_app.tests', ])
    def tearDown(self):
        call_command('migrate', 'my_app.tests', 'zero',  interactive=False)

    @override_settings(INSTALLED_APPS=settings.INSTALLED_APPS + ['my_app.tests', ])
    def test_auto_slug_creation(self):
        c1 = UniqueSlugTestModel(name='Company 1')
        c1.save()
        c1.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(c1.slug, 'company-1')

    @override_settings(INSTALLED_APPS=settings.INSTALLED_APPS + ['my_app.tests', ])
    def test_unique_slug_generation(self):
        usm = UniqueSlugTestModel(name='Company 1')
        usm.save()
        usm.refresh_from_db()
        usm2 = UniqueSlugTestModel(name='Company  1')
        usm2.save()
        usm2.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertNotEqual(usm.slug, usm2.slug)
```

The `print(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)` prints out all of my installed apps including the `my_app.tests` app that I have added in there.

But it fails with `App 'my_app.tests' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?`

Comment: Do you have an __init__.py file in the my_app/tests directory?  Python requires there be one of those in every module you are trying to include in your INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt Yes

Comment: Gotcha.  The only other thing I can think of is that maybe the `override_settings` call is messing with the application's actual `settings.py`.  That or maybe the command you are running is causing some sort of problem?  Sorry I can't be much more help

Comment: @MichaelPlatt Well I think the problem is that it isn't messing with the actual settings and the call to `call_command` is looking at the actual settings instead of the in memory ones.

Comment: I wish I could give you an answer on this.  I just tried setting things up the way you have them in a Django app we have at work and things ran fine.  This leaves me to believe it's not a problem with how you are modifying your INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.  Not sure if that helps rules anything out but I figure any info is better than none at this point.